# Removing colon from a time stamp

Tags: regex, sed

I have a datetimestamp like:

```
 07/May/2012:00:00:01
```

I wish to remove the colon between the date and time and replace it with a space.

I try:

```
sed -e 's/....:../.... ../g' local.csv > local07_nocolon.csv
```

But that give me:

```
07/May/.... ..:00:01
```

Any tips appreciated....

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to remove only the first colon then you can try this

```
echo "07/May/2012:00:00:01" | sed 's/:/ /'
```

If you need to remove all colons then use this

```
echo "07/May/2012:00:00:01" | sed 's/:/ /g'
```

Comment: That's good. But is there any way I could do it so it is the first colan after the 4 digits?

Comment: Try this if you want to match 4 colons  echo "07/May/2012:00:00:01" | sed -e 's/\(..\)\/\(...\)\/\(....\):\(..\):\(..\)/\1\/\2\/\3 \4:\5/g'

Answer (score 1):

Use capturing groups and backreferences (and make sure to match only digits):

```
sed -e 's/\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\):\([0-9][0-9]\)/\1 \2/g' local.csv > local07_nocolon.csv
```

Edit: I had forgotten that [POSIX EREs do not support the `\d` shorthand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8268190/20670). Now it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The below sed command replaces all occurrences of : to " " using global substitution flag “g”.

```
sed 's/:/ /g' local.csv > local07_nocolon.csv
```

and the output of the file will be in the form of

```
07/May/2012 00 00 01
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
echo "07/May/2012:00:00:01" | sed 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\):/\1 /g' file
07/May/2012 00:00:01
```

or:

```
echo "07/May/2012:00:00:01" | sed 's/\([[:digit:]]\{4\}\):/\1 /g'
07/May/2012 00:00:01
```