# bash - print regex captured groups

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep, pattern-matching

I have a **file.xml** so composed:

```
...some xml text here...
    <Version>1.0.13-alpha</Version>
...some xml text here...
```

I need to extract the following information:

- *mayor_and_minor_release_number* --> 1.0
- *patch_number* --> 13
- *suffix* --> -alpha

I've thought the cleanest way to achieve that is by mean of a regex with **grep** command:

```
<Version>(\d+\.\d+)\.(\d+)([\w-]+)?<\/Version>
```

I've checked with [regex101](https://regex101.com/) the correctness of this regex and actually it seems to properly capture the 3 fields I'm looking for. But here comes the problem, since I have no idea how to print those fields.

```
cat file.xml | grep "<Version>(\d+\.\d+)\.(\d+)([\w-]+)?<\/Version>" -oP
```

This command prints the entire line so it's quite useless.

Several posts on this site have been written about this topic, so I've also tried to use the *bash native
regex support*, with poor results:

```
regex="<Version>(\d+\.\d+)\.(\d+)([\w-]+)?<\/Version>"
txt=$(cat file.xml)
[[ "$txt" =~ $regex ]]     --> it fails!
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[*]}"
```

I'm sorry but I cannot figure out how to overtake this issue. The desired output should be:

```
1.0
13
-alpha
```

Comment: @Shawn Yes you're right. I've forgotten to mention I cannot use any tool other than pure **bash**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268138/does-posix-extended-regular-expressions-supports-the-d-metacharacter might be helpful.

Comment: Once again a user is asking for regex help and `regex` tag was removed. I am restoring it again but this is not good for SO.

Comment: @LéaGris generally speaking, you're right. But, in my opinion, parsing a single tag in a whole xml files is not a task which cannot be carried out by bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `read + sed` solution with similar regex as your's:

```sh
read -r major minor suffix < <(
sed -nE 's~.*<Version>([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)(-[^<]*)</Version>.*~\1 \2 \3~p' file.xml
)
```

**Check variable contents:**

```sh
declare -p major minor suffix

declare -- major="1.0"
declare -- minor="13"
declare -- suffix="-alpha"
```

Few points:

- You cannot use `\d` without using `-P` (perl) mode in `grep`
- `grep` command doesn't return capture groups

Comment: It works like a charm.Thank you. I know very little about *sed*. However, I'd like to know whether it is possible to achieve same result using just *RE_MATCHES*.

Comment: Without using `\d` we can use `<Version>([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)(-[^<]*)</Version>` as regex in `bash` and get captured groups in `"${BASH_REMATCH[@]}"` but `bash` regex is more suitable for matching against a string. If we are trying to find a match in a file then we'll need to match in a loop or read full file in a string like `data="$(<file.xml)"`

Answer (score 1):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -lne 'print for m{<Version>(\d+\.\d+)\.(\d+)([\w-]+)?<\/Version>};' file.xml
```

Example:

```
echo '<Version>1.0.13-alpha</Version>' | perl -lne 'print for m{<Version>(\d+\.\d+)\.(\d+)([\w-]+)?<\/Version>};'
```

Output:

```
1.0
13
-alpha
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)